# using CURL to transmit binary data over POST parameter

Tags: linux, bash, curl, binary, data

How can i use CURL to send binary data through a specific post parameter?
E.g in:

```
curl 'http://www.example.com' -H 'hi:hi' --data 'utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=put&file=binarydatahere&submit=confirm'
```

I want to send the binary data through the file parameter, I've heard of the `--data-binary @myfile.bin` method, but i fail to see how i can specify to which parameter the binary data goes through.

Answer (score 5):

Put the name of the parameter in front of the `@`, like this:

```
--data-binary file@myfile.bin
```

From the `curl` [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> **name@filename** This will make curl load data from the given file
>   (including any newlines), URL-encode that data and pass it on in the
>   POST. The name part gets an equal sign appended, resulting in
>   name=urlencoded-file-content. Note that the name is expected to be
>   URL-encoded already.

Comment: How do i get the response of the post request? Thanks a lot :).